# Landsat 8 OLI Tasseled Cap Transformation Calculation ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, arcgis-10.3, landsat-8

I need to calculate the TCT greenness for Landsat 8 OLI imagery and having a hard time finding a tool.

All the python scripts I have found do not work and I am not experienced with Python at all.

Can anyone please point me to a step by step tutorial or just personal experience with this?

Comment: Can you convert your Landsat 8 data to at-satellite reflectance? This is a required first step. If you don't, then that'll tell us where to start.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you and alternative: the r package [RStoolbox](http://bleutner.github.io/RStoolbox/).

The package provide the [Tasseled Cap Transformation](http://bleutner.github.io/RStoolbox/rstbx-docu/tasseledCap.html) for Landsat 4 TM, Landsat 5 TM, Landsat 7ETM+, Landsat 8 OLI and MODIS.

Source code may be accessed from [github repository](https://github.com/bleutner/RStoolbox/blob/master/R/tasseledCap.R).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you should be able to do that in ArcGIS. Here is the link that explains it. http://geospatialworld.net/Paper/Application/ArticleView.aspx?aid=460

You can use ENVI or ERDAS to do the NDVI as well.

For more info on Landsat 8 http://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat8.php